# From Mac iOS to Linux

Tags: linux, macos, shell, terminal, cdr

I have a CDR file with binary code and code written on Perl to decode CDR file.

Now I use Mac, but next week I will start to use Linux.
I've never used Linux before.

If now I use terminal to decode my files and I use this command:

```
    cat 201301101536_00240349.cdr | ./huawei2text.pl >
     ~/Desktop/201301101536_00240349.txt && 
 cat ~/Desktop/201301101536_00240349.txt| tr "," "\n"  > 
     ~/Desktop/out_201301101536_00240349.txt
```

Using this command I decode my file with Perl decoder, then write in txt file, then I change "," to "\n" - new line and save it in new txt file.

Now a question, Is it a same command in linux to do all these actions.

Thank you in advance

Comment: As long as you have an equivalent version of Perl running on Linux, that looks like pretty straight-forward shell work that should also work on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short words: yes.

Unless you have two different perl versions on your mac and linux distribution, but I doubt that.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to write a script to decode all files, because now I do it one by one. And it takes ages to finish. If there is a same way doing it on Mac and Linux in the future

Comment: Please ask a single question per "question". Only than this platform will stay as clear.

Comment: I have already posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234061/script-to-automatisation